# How do I instantiate a paint method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, paint, instantiation

```java
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Polygon extends JApplet{

  public static void main (String[] args) {

    int i,j;

    int poly[]=new int[6];
    System.out.println("Enter 3 pairs of coordinates for the polygon:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    for (i=0;i<poly.length;i++) {
      poly[i]=scan.nextInt();
    }

    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    poly.paint(g);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {   
    g.drawLine(20, 20, 200, 200);
  }
}
```

I am trying to instantiate my paint method so that I can use the user inputted array values to use as coordinates for the g.drawLine(). When I try to instantiate this method I am receiving an error on the g in poly.paint(g). Can anyone give me some guidance on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: The concept of instantiation applies to classes, not methods.

Comment: You haven't defined what `g` is there.

Comment: You really need to read an introductory tutorial about Java. Then practice with simple exercises not involving Swing. Then, read an introductory tutorial about Swing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Should be something like this


public void paint(Graphics g) {   
    g.drawLine(20, 20, 200, 200);

    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    poly.paint(g);
}
```

Where you're using `g` within the containing scope